# Constraints in Embeddable inside an ElementCollection are ignored for DDL

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Given these classes (in Java):

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    public UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @ElementCollection
    public Set<Child> children;
}

@Embeddable
public class Child {
    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 20)
    public String s;
}
```

I would expect Hibernate to auto-generate the following table for the `Child` class:

```
CREATE TABLE public.parent_children
(
    parent_id uuid NOT NULL,
    children_s character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ...
)
```

But it ignores the constraints in the Embeddable and generates:

```
CREATE TABLE public.parent_children
(
    parent_id uuid NOT NULL,
    children_s character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT ...
)
```

1) What can I do to solve this problem (still using Hibernate's auto-dll feature)?

2) As a related question, what can I do so Hibernate does not add the prefix `children_` to the column names? I know I can do:

```
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="s", column=@Column(name="s"))
})
public Set<Child> children;
```

But that seems quite ugly to me.

---

- Spring Boot 2.0.5
- Hibernate Core 5.2.17

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for using the validation constraints in embeddables? I want to apply a @Min constraint to a property inside an embeddable.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question. I think the problem only was that DDL did not work as expected. Object validation should be without issues. If you want a min constraint in your database, use the `@Column` annotation.

Comment: Apparently, `@Column` does only generate a constraint about the length of the column. But I can not specify like `> 1`. :/ I agree with you, it's only the DDL which is not working as expected. :) Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing `@NotNull` and `@Length` are `javax.validation.constraints`, those are for validation only.

Your `@Embeddable` should look like this

```
@Embeddable
public class Child {

    @Column(name="s", nullable=false)
    public String s;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. Hibernate does use these validation constraints for DDL in other situations. (I think I read somewhere this is not JPA standard behavior.) Nevertheless, your solution works and is not too verbose. I can also specify the length with `@Column(name="s", nullable=false, length = 20)`. Thanks!